# Trying to pass a array to a method to be sorted

Tags: ruby

Codeacademy actually passed this code as correct but got these errors when built in irb. I'm lost!

Errors: (ruby):1: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
(ruby):8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

```
    def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    if rev = true
        arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
    else 
        arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2 }
    end
end
    puts arr
end
alphabetize("the", "world", "is", "a", "vampire")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `if rev = true` as `if rev == true`(but more Rubyish is `if rev`). There is an extra `end` also just above `puts arr`, remove it.

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  if rev 
    arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
  else 
    arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2 }
  end
end

puts alphabetize(["the", "world", "is", "a", "vampire"])
```

Comment: Well, by mistake (or you know this exercise from Codeacademy) you have answered future question of the author: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21197448/2597260

Comment: @DarekNędza I saw that... OP took other answer, and trapped in gap.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be like this:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    if rev == true
        arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
    else 
        arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2 }
    end
    puts arr
end
alphabetize(["the", "world", "is", "a", "vampire"])
```

you have extra `end`, and `rev==true` is the comparison, you are using `rev=true` which is assignment

> another mistake is when calling the method you need to pass an array