# Is code academy wrong here?

Tags: ruby

CodeAcademy's Error: Oops, try again. It looks like your method doesn't default to alphabetizing an array when it doesn't receive a second parameter.

```
    def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    if rev == true
        arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
    else 
        arr.sort! 
    end
    puts arr
end

alphabetize(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

EDIT:
Here are the objectives of this section (sorry for not including originally):

> 1) Add an if/else statement inside your method. If rev is true, it
>   should sort the array reverse-alphabetically; if rev is false (which
>   happens if the user passes false or doesn't pass an argument for rev
>   at all), it should sort the array in alphabetical order.
>
> 2) Outside your method, puts the sorted array. (This is so you can see
>   all the fine work your method did.)
>
> 3) Call your method on an array of your choice to see it in action!

Comment: If it requires that `alphabetize` **return** the sorted array, then code academy is correct - you're not returning the array, you're just printing it out via `puts`.

Comment: Ruby returns the result of the last executed line of a method., which happens to be `puts arr`. `puts` returns `nil`. Try using `p arr` (`p` retuns it's argument, `arr`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) Outside your method, puts the sorted array.

Not inside, like you did. `puts arr` returns nil, codeacademy wants array as return value. Outside you should `puts` return value from this method outside:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    if rev == true
        arr.sort! { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
    else 
        arr.sort! 
    end
    arr
end

puts alphabetize(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

ps. as Wayne Conrad noted in the comment, `sort!` modify your array.

```
arr1=[2,3,1,5,22]
# => [2, 3, 1, 5, 22]
alphabetize arr1
# => [1, 2, 3, 5, 22]
arr1
# => [1, 2, 3, 5, 22] # you didn't want this array changed, right?
```

You should use normal `sort` that doesn't change array if you don't want array to change.
`!` also know as *bang* suggest dangerous method, in this case it modify the array.

Comment: It's worth nothing that the OP's use of `sort!` should be changed to just `sort`.  Usually, a function should either have no side-effects and return a value, or have side-effects and return nothing.

Comment: @wayne-conrad  Well, I edited the answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the array as return value to your function.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include an if/else statement.
I ran this code and Codecademy accepted it.
You are suppose to return the ordered array and then `puts` the result in console after method is called.

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  arr.sort!
  return arr
end

puts numbers

numbers = [2,1,9,3]
alphabetize(numbers)
```

Comment: This is in section 5: Ordering your library. In lesson 4, you don't need an if/else statement. Lesson 5 you DO need an if/else statement.